# Is it possible to export a large R table into a PDF file?

Tags: r, pdf, export-to-pdf

I need to export a table I made in r from binding different values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEcIu.png)

I've tried with `library(gridExtra)` but it's not working (perhaphs I'm using it wrong)

````
FA=table(ant$municipionombre)
View(FA)
prop.table(table(ant$municipionombre))


#Percentage Relative Frequency/Frecuencia relativa porcentual
FR=FA/margin.table(FA)
View(FR)


#Cumulative Absolute Frequency/Frecuencia absoluta acumulada
FAA=cumsum(FA)
View(FAA)

#Cumulative Percentage Relative Frequency/Frecuencia relativa porcentual acumulada
FRP=cumsum(FA)/margin.table(FA)
View(FRP)

#Percentage by entry
perc=FR*100
perc

#Build a table with all variables (FA, FAA, FR, FRP, perc)
tab1=cbind(FA,FAA,FR,FRP,perc)
tab1
View(tab1)```
````

Comment: Have you considered `rmarkdown` package for exporting the table to pdf and `kableExtra` for the table styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your code above, as you haven't provided useable sample data.  But the fundamental question of how to export data to a PDF can be accomplished with the reporter package.

There are three steps:

1. Create the table content.
2. Create a report.
3. Write out the report.

Here is an example using the *iris* data frame.

```
library(reporter)


tbl <- create_table(iris) %>% 
  titles("My PDF Report")

rpt <- create_report("c:\\temp\\test.pdf", output_type = "PDF") %>% 
  add_content(tbl)


write_report(rpt)
```

Here is a portion of the PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With using gridExtra package, you may consider following code below

```
    maxrow = 35;
    npages = ceiling(nrow(df)/maxrow)
    pdf("test.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5)  
    idx = seq(1, maxrow)        
    grid.table(df[idx,], rows = NULL)
    for (i in 2:npages){
      grid.newpage()
      if(i * maxrow <= nrow(df)) {
        idx = seq(1 + ((1 - 1) * maxrow), i*maxrow)
      } else {
        idx = seq(1 + ((i - 1) * naxriw), nrow(df))
      }
      grid.table(df[idx,], rows = NULL)
    }
    dev.off()
```

You may change height or width so I highly recommend try to make pdf with single page. Also df is table to write pdf.